# Speech Recognition and Macros for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, macros, speech-recognition

Recently I have been working on a little project involving speech recognition in Windows, I used the Windows Speech Recognition software that comes pre-installed and also the Windows Speech Recognition Macros tool which allowed me to associate certain phrases with actions that would be automatically carried out. I have also included additional pre-recorded voice clips which were played while the action was carried out so it would appear that the computer is talking (little like JARVIS in Iron Man) :P.

For example if I said "open twitter" the macro would navigate to a shortcut of twitter.

Lately I have experienced some issues with my Windows on the computer running this speech recognition "system" causing the whole thing to malfunction. I want to put a linux-based system (either Ubuntu or Linux-Mint) on the computer.

Before I do so, I would like to know whether there is an open-source alternative which would allow me to do the same thing but on linux? I would be preferably looking for something rather easy to use as I am still a newbie when it comes to linux.

Could you please advise me on any programs that you know of and perhaps of ways that I could replicate my Speech Assistant?

Thank you.
Jakub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite many alternatives on Linux. Most common of them are

[Simon](http://simon-listens.org/index.php?id=122&L=1)

[Palaver](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver)

Both are pretty easy to extend even for unexperienced user.

For more advanced speech recognition development you can check an open source speech recognition engine CMUSphin

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will give both of them a try. Would they support something in shape of described above MARCO's ?

Comment: Yes, they both upport same them